# WooCommerce get products by attribute query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I have a product with attribute colors.  Attribute values are red, blue and green.  I am trying to create a custom search but I can't get the query to pull any product.

```
$args =  array(
    'post_type'      => array('product'),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array( 
        array(
            'key' => '_visibility',
            'value' => array('catalog', 'visible'),
            'compare' => 'IN',  
        ) 
    ),
    'tax_query'      => array( 
        array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'product',
            'field'           => 'slug',
            'terms'           =>  array('blue', 'red', 'green'),
            'operator'        => 'IN',
        ),
    )
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The correct taxonomy for the product attribute color is **`'pa_color'`**, so the correct working query is:

```
// The query
$products = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'      => array('product'),
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query'     => array( array(
        'key' => '_visibility',
        'value' => array('catalog', 'visible'),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ) ),
   'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'terms'           =>  array('blue', 'red', 'green'),
        'operator'        => 'IN',
    ) )
) );

// The Loop
if ( $products->have_posts() ): while ( $products->have_posts() ):
    $products->the_post();
    $product_ids[] = $products->post->ID;
endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

// TEST: Output the Products IDs
print_r($product_ids);
```

This code is tested and works. You will get all products that have Color attribute with the values (terms) 'blue', 'red' and 'green'…

> Since WooCommerce 3, **product visibility** is handled by custom taxonomy `product_visibility`. You can see the following related threads:
>
> - [Database changes for products in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482690/database-changes-for-products-in-woocommerce-3/48487242#48487242)
> - [Get products which are visible in catalog in a WP_query on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658379/get-products-which-are-visible-in-catalog-in-a-wp-query-on-woocommerce/53661330#53661330)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working for me and I don't understand why.

Comment: @user3098629 I have test it on my test server, and for me it perfectly works. Anyway, the correct taxonomy for the attribute "Color" is `pa_color`. All product attributes taxonomy slugs start alway by `pa_` …

Comment: Is there anything in the actual product that needs to be setup for this to work?  I have a product that is visible and shows up everywhere else except this query.

Comment: I got it working....apparently the meta query was causing problems and causing it to return nothing.  THanks for your help

Comment: Since Woocommerce 3 you no longer use `meta_query` to exlude hidden products, you will need to use `tax_query` detailed here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231118/wp-query-exclude-hidden-products-from-woocommerce-product-list/262628#262628