# How to search product on basis of it's attribute via api for woocommrce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have been searching product on basis of their attribute by the refference of 
woocommerce  v1 api documentation.following is the sample code that i tried

```
$args = array(
                "page" => "1",
                "status" => "publish",
                "attribute" => Array
                    (
                        "name" => "Color",
                        "options" => Array("Loft Gray")
                    )
            );

$getProducts = $woocommerce->get('products',$args);
```

Comment: you just provided some array from some function. provide the full code

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan code has been updated...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers of your question. Here are some examples from them:

[From here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240283/get-product-attributes-for-current-product-and-store-it-in-a-variable):

```
$brand_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'pa_liquor-brands' );
```

[And here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374883/woocommerce-getting-custom-attributes):

```
$product->get_attribute( 'your_attr' );
```

Instead of getting page $args, define `global $product` and extract from it any attributes you need.

Getting `products` using `attributes`( your question answer, got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45828742/8053001)  ):

```
// The query
$products = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'      => array('product'),
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query'     => array( array(
      'key' => '_visibility',
      'value' => array('catalog', 'visible'),
      'compare' => 'IN',
  ) ),
  'tax_query'      => array( array(
      'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
      'field'           => 'slug',
      'terms'           =>  array('blue', 'red', 'green'),
      'operator'        => 'IN',
   ) )
) );

// The Loop
if ( $products->have_posts() ): while ( $products->have_posts() ):
    $products->the_post();
    $product_ids[] = $products->post->ID;
endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

// TEST: Output the Products IDs
print_r($product_ids);
```