# Handle Woocommerce visibility for hidden products in a WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

Can you help me with this? I have a product list and what I want is to hide those products marked as hidden on the visibility detail of the product. Here's the code I have:

```
 $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                        'terms' => $product_categories[$wc_arr_key[$wc_cat_id]]->term_id,
                        'visibility' => 'visible' //NOT WORKING...
                    )
                ),
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'orderby'    => 'menu_order',      
                'order'           =>  'ASC',      

            );
            $products = new WP_Query( $args );

            if(isset($_GET['staging']) && $_GET['staging'] == "true") {
                echo "<pre>" . print_r($products) . "</pre>";
            }
```

I want to display all the products that are marked as visible.

Answer (score 2):

Since Woocommerce 3 the product visibility is handled by the taxonomy `product_visibility` for the term `exclude-from-catalog`, so you need to use a second array in your tax query array:

```
$terms = array( $product_categories[$wc_arr_key[$wc_cat_id]]->term_id );

$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => $terms
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_visibility',
            'terms'     => array('exclude-from-catalog'),
            'field'     => 'name',
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'order'             =>  'ASC',
) );


if(isset($_GET['staging']) && $_GET['staging'] == "true") {
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($products) . "</pre>";
}
```

Tested and works.

Related: [Database changes for products in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482690/database-changes-for-products-in-woocommerce-3/48487242#48487242)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to exclude `hidden` products and display only `visible` ones

```
$args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                        'terms' => $product_categories[$wc_arr_key[$wc_cat_id]]->term_id
                    )
                ),
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                       'key'       => '_visibility',
                       'value'     => 'hidden',
                       'compare'   => '!='
                         )
                 ),
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'orderby'    => 'menu_order',      
                'order'           =>  'ASC'      

            );
            $products = new WP_Query( $args );

            if(isset($_GET['staging']) && $_GET['staging'] == "true") {
                echo "<pre>" . print_r($products) . "</pre>";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce save this data as metadata so you'll need to run a Meta Query against the name _visibility. This will look like

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'       => '_visibility',
        'value'     => 'hidden',
        'compare'   => '!=',
    )
)
```

This will pull all posts that do not have meta _visibility equal to hidden