# How to make WordPress/WooCommerce search function search product tags and products only?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am having some trouble making my wordpress search query, search for WooCommerce products and tags/keywords. It would also be great to have it search categories.

Currently I've gotten it to search WooCommerce products only, but still need the tags/keywords and would also be great to get the product categories search results as well

Also the tags/keywords may very some, so it has to be dynamic, so that the customer or me don't have to update it once in a while.

```php
// Only search woocommerce products not posts and pages
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_only_products' );
function search_only_products( $query ) {
  if( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $args = array(
        
        );
        $query->set(    'post_type', 'product', 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_visibility',
                'value' => 'hidden',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_visibility',
                'value' => 'hidden',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ));
        // $query->set($args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Limits search results to only show products
 *
 * @param WP_Query $wp_query The main WP_Query object
 * @return void
 */
function limit_search_to_products( $wp_query ) {
    
    // Only limit frontend search queries for main query
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Get search term
        $search_term = $wp_query->get( 's' );

        // Split search term into an array of keywords
        $keywords_array = preg_split(
            "/[\s-]+/",
            $search_term,
            -1,
            PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
        );

        if ( ! empty( $keywords_array ) ) {

            global $wpdb;
            
            // Array to hold product IDs that match the search term keywords
            $tag_filtered_product_ids_unorganized = array();

            $wp_query_hash = md5( serialize( $wp_query->query_vars ) );

            // Check if the result of the tag query has already been cached
            $catch_of_tag_query_result = get_transient( $wp_query_hash . '_for_custom_tag_search' );

            // Check if the result of the tag query has already been cached
            if( false === $catch_of_tag_query_result ) {

                // Loop through each keyword to search for products with matching tags or categories
                foreach ( $keywords_array as $keyword ) {
    
                    // Query to find products for matching tags or categories
                    $tag_search_query = $wpdb->prepare( "
                        SELECT p.ID, p.post_type, p.post_status
                        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
                        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships AS tr ON p.id = tr.object_id
                        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy AS tt ON ( tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND ( tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' OR tt.taxonomy = 'product_tag' ) )
                        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
                        WHERE t.name LIKE %s AND p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                    ", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $keyword ) . '%' );
    
                    // Get search query results
                    $tag_search_query_results = $wpdb->get_results( $tag_search_query );
    
                    if ( ! empty( $tag_search_query_results ) ) {
                        // Loop through search query results to collect product IDs
                        foreach ( $tag_search_query_results as $tag_search_query_result ) {
                            array_push(
                                $tag_filtered_product_ids_unorganized,
                                $tag_search_query_result->ID
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ( ! empty( $tag_filtered_product_ids_unorganized ) ) {

                    // Count how many times each product ID appears in the array of search results
                    $count_product_ids_in_array = array_count_values( $tag_filtered_product_ids_unorganized );

                    // Total number of keywords in search term
                    $total_keywords = count( $keywords_array );

                    // Filter the array of product IDs to only include those that match all keywords
                    $tag_filtered_product_ids_unorganized = array_filter(
                        $count_product_ids_in_array,
                        function ( $number_of_occurrences_of_product_id_in_array )
                            use ( $total_keywords ) {
                                return $number_of_occurrences_of_product_id_in_array == $total_keywords;
                        }
                    );                    
                }
                // Final array of product IDs that match the search term keywords for tags or categories
                $tag_filtered_product_ids = array_keys( $tag_filtered_product_ids_unorganized );

                // Cache the result
                set_transient( $wp_query_hash . '_for_custom_tag_search', serialize( $tag_filtered_product_ids ), 3600 );

            }
            else {
                // If the tag query result is already cached, retrieve it
                $tag_filtered_product_ids = unserialize( $catch_of_tag_query_result );
            }
        }

        // If products found that matches tags or categories
        if ( isset( $tag_filtered_product_ids ) && ! empty( $tag_filtered_product_ids ) ) {

            // Get product IDs from default search query
            $query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;
            $query_vars['post_type'] = 'product';
            $query_vars['fields'] = 'ids';
            $query_vars['posts_per_page'] = -1;
            $query = new WP_Query( $query_vars );
            $search_result_products_id = $query->posts;
            wp_reset_postdata();wp_reset_query();

            // Get the product IDs that appear in both the default search query and the custom tag search query
            $merged_search_results = array_unique(
                array_merge(
                    $search_result_products_id,
                    $tag_filtered_product_ids
                )
            );

            // Set the search parameter to false to prevent it from interfering with the product list
            // By setting it to false, this change the default search page title tag from being displayed correctly
            // But the second function (which I add bellow in this answer) to control the search page title tag
            $wp_query->set( 's', false );

            // Set the product IDs that we want to display in the search results
            $wp_query->set( 'post__in', $merged_search_results );

            // Order the search results by the merged product ID array to maintain the default search order and add the custom tag search results to the end
            $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );

        }
        
        // Set post type to the product only
        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', 'product' );

        // Get only visible products
        // Now, Woocommerce use tax_query instead of meta_query
        # https://woocommerce.com/posts/woocommerce-3-0-release/
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487242/20896084
        $wp_query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_visibility',
            'terms'     => array('exclude-from-catalog'),
            'field'     => 'name',
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_search_to_products' );
```

I've added multiple comments that explains what's going on in the code and I think that is more easy way to understand this long code, rather then all explanation in one paragraph.

It's 100% working but I suggest to build custom search functionality from the scratch that is more flexible, easier to built & customizable rather than this change in WP search functionality.

---

If you read all the code above then hear is the second function that solve search page title tag issue created by my answer and more explanation about it.

In my answer i do this : `$wp_query->set( 's', false );`

**Reason :** I use  `post__in`  to display all the post, but if  `s`  exist in query then  `post__in`  doesn't work that way I want it to.

**Explanation :** if `s` gives us products  `array(1,2,3,4,5)`  and  `post__in`  has  `array(3,5,7,9)`  that result is  `array(3,5)` , but that is not we want, we want all post in  `post__in` , so i set `s` to be false.

That's why we get nothing from [get_search_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/#source) and that is use to set search page title tag ( hook i use for fix : [document_title_parts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) )

```
<?php
/**
 * Modify the part of the document title for the search page
 *
 * @param array $title Default document title, page number, site name & description
 * @return array $title
 */
function set_title_tag_for_search_page( $title ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_search() && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $search_query_parameter = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( esc_attr( $_GET['s'] ) ) );
        $blog_name    = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        $search_title = sprintf( __( 'Search Results for &#8220;%s&#8221;', 'text-domain' ), $search_query_parameter );
        $title['title'] = html_entity_decode( $search_title, ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'set_title_tag_for_search_page' );
```

I've add images for better understanding

| If you use don't second function | If you use second function |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before fix] | [image: After fix] |
| [image: Before fix] | [image: After fix] |