# Get products which are visible in catalog in a WP_query on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently trying to get all products in a category page which are visible in catalog. I've tried this here but I'm getting no products with this query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'product_cat' => get_queried_object()->slug,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_visibility',
            'value'   => array( 'catalog', 'visible' ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

var_dump( $loop );
```

When I remove the `meta_query` visibility part I'm getting all products including the hidden ones but I just need the visible ones. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This need to be a tax query instead *(as since woocommerce 3 it is now handled by `product_visibility` custom taxonomy)*:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'product_cat' => get_queried_object()->slug,
    'tax_query'   => array( array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_visibility',
        'terms'     => array( 'exclude-from-catalog' ),
        'field'     => 'name',
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
    ) )
) );

var_dump( $loop );
```

This should better work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!