# How I can get all id's of taxonomy term_id Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

How can i fetch products by terms?
in taxonomy pa_color i have a lot of colors inside and i can't write all names in array
how i can fetch all products with all terms id?

```
'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'terms'           =>  all,
        'operator'        => 'IN',
    ) )
) );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce get products by attribute query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828655/woocommerce-get-products-by-attribute-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'operator'        => 'EXISTS',
    ) )
) );
```